# Stop Band Fills from extending beyond x Axis CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

i have a little problem with alternating band fills in CorePlot. I'm setting the band fills like this

```
x.alternatingBandFills = @[_majorBandFill,_minorBandFill];
```

with `_majorBandFill` and `_minorBandFill` being `CPTFill` IVars.

This results in the following:

[image]

As you can see the band fills extend beyond the Y Axis and overlap my Labels.

Is there a way to stop the band fills from extending beyond the axis? I do not want to move the labels further down.

Thanks in Advance

Malte

Answer (score 0):

The band fills normally extend from one edge of the plot area to the other. You can set the `gridLinesRange` to limit the grid lines and band fills to a different range.